# How to Resize Webview when Keyboard is dismissed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I've got the following code:

```
- (void)messageComposerFrameDidChange:(CGRect)frame withAnimationDuration:(float)duration {

    self.webViewBottomConstraint.constant = _keyboardFrame.size.height-15 + frame.size.height;
    UIScrollView *scrollView = self.chatConversation.scrollView;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height, scrollView.contentSize.width, 1);
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];

    NSInteger height = [[_chatConversation stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] intValue];
    NSString* javascript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollBy(0, %d);", height];
    [_chatConversation stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
}
```

This code works perfectly, the only issue I've is that when I dismiss the keyboard it shows the Webview just where it was instead of resizing it back to its normal position. Aligned to the textview height.

The WebView Property is  `_chatConversation` as you can see in the image

Here is the Log Values

When Keyboard is closed when Chat Windows is shown: ( Screen 1 )

```
2014-09-30 10:57:52.391 mobile-app[737:260398] +-------------------------------------------------+
2014-09-30 10:57:52.392 mobile-app[737:260398] Keyboard Frame: **0.000000**
2014-09-30 10:57:52.392 mobile-app[737:260398] Frame Position Y Position: 512.500000
2014-09-30 10:57:52.393 mobile-app[737:260398] Chat Conversation Height: 401.000000
2014-09-30 10:57:52.393 mobile-app[737:260398] Chat Conversation Y Position: 64.000000
2014-09-30 10:57:52.393 mobile-app[737:260398] +-------------------------------------------------+
```

When the user taps to type a message (Screen 2)

```
2014-09-30 10:58:48.265 mobile-app[737:260398] +-------------------------------------------------+
2014-09-30 10:58:48.266 mobile-app[737:260398] Keyboard Frame: **253.000000**
2014-09-30 10:58:48.266 mobile-app[737:260398] Frame Position Y Position: 259.500000
2014-09-30 10:58:48.267 mobile-app[737:260398] Chat Conversation Height: 463.500000
2014-09-30 10:58:48.267 mobile-app[737:260398] Chat Conversation Y Position: 64.000000
2014-09-30 10:58:48.267 mobile-app[737:260398] +-------------------------------------------------+
```

When the user taps back to dismiss the keyboard ( Screen 3 )

```
2014-09-30 10:59:15.098 mobile-app[737:260398] +-------------------------------------------------+
2014-09-30 10:59:15.098 mobile-app[737:260398] Keyboard Frame: **253.000000**
2014-09-30 10:59:15.098 mobile-app[737:260398] Frame Position Y Position: 512.500000
2014-09-30 10:59:15.099 mobile-app[737:260398] Chat Conversation Height: 210.500000
2014-09-30 10:59:15.099 mobile-app[737:260398] Chat Conversation Y Position: 64.000000
2014-09-30 10:59:15.099 mobile-app[737:260398] +-------------------------------------------------+
```

[image]

IF you see screen 3 and the log, Keyboard Frame its 253 instead of 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code my guess is that your problem could be on this line:

```
 self.webViewBottomConstraint.constant = _keyboardFrame.size.height-15 + frame.size.height;
```

The frame returned by `messageComposerFrameDidChange` will also have a `origin.y` so it might be easier just to use that directly rather than manually track `_keyboardFrame`. Have you verified that `_keyboardFrame.size.height == 0` when the delegate call comes in after the keyboard has been dismissed?

Another possibility might be that `UIWebView` actually did resize properly and instead the content scrolling isn't working as expected which is causing the issue in screen 3.

Comment: yes. the Keyboardframe is 0. here is a log http://pastie.org/9607414 of the size changes when it shows keyboard and dismiss it.

Comment: When the keyboard is dismissed the height is not 0 as you mention instead its 512.

Comment: Which value does "Keyboard Frame" correspond to? Also Chat Conversation Height: gets *larger* between screen 1 and 2 which makes no sense given the screenshots provided.

Comment: Can't you just use the value of Frame Position Y Position to set your chat conversation height? It seems to be correct in all three frames. It is 512.500000 when the keyboard is down and 259.500000 when the keyboard is visible.

Comment: The solution I've found is to add http://pastie.org/9608515 but still stome little frame like some sort of marging. when it hides.